# Can´t convert raw grayscale 12 bit picture to color

Tags: c++, opencv, grayscale, color-conversion

I have to convert a raw image to color. My informations about the Image are:

- the color-depth is 12 bit
- I have to use Bayer-Patern to convert it
- 1 (color) Pixel has 1 value for red in the raw-image and 3 gray values (I have really no idea, how this should work)

You can see a part of the raw-image here: http://relin.de/0.pgm

But if I try to debayer it, I get only a 1-color picture like this: http://relin.de/0.ppm

I use c++ and opencv. My source-code:

```
Mat iSource(height, width, CVMatType, (char*)pData);
Mat z, zz;
iSource.convertTo(z, CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, 1), 0.0625);
cvtColor(z, zz, CV_BayerGB2RGB);
```

I have also tried to look at values of that parts of the image, where I know which color there should be (traffic-signs).

Where Blue should be, are this values in the raw image:
00 05
05 05

Red:
08 08
08 08

White:
0D 56
56 56

Green(probably):
11 5F 
50 5E

That seems not to be a bayer pattern.

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: That raw image you posted is only 8bit...

Comment: Yes, i converted the picture down to 8Bit (this is the version i work with). An unconverted 12bit images is here: http://relin.de/09.pgm